# where not in select from db

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to figure out why this code doesn't work; i'm trying to select "upgrades" from the database that the user doesn't already have. I've done it two ways

This Way:

```
SELECT id, name, cost, prereq, nullif FROM upgrades WHERE NOT IN (Select upgrade_id  FROM user_upgrades WHERE uid = :uid);
```

and this way:

```
  SELECT id, name, cost, prereq, nullif FROM upgrades WHERE NOT IN (:ID)
```

in which the :ID tag isa list of user upgrades pulled through a function in PHP. Neither one of these codes are working--they do not show any results whats so ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the attribute in the condition after WHERE:

```
WHERE "MISSING ATTRIBUTE" NOT IN ...
```

Comment: ...

Please feel free to call me stupid... how the HELL did i miss that.